# How can I make Multiplication Matrix in Python Code?

Tags: python

I'd be happy if you tell me, what I need to change in the code "**This Is My Code**" to get "**This is My Target**"

**This Is My Code**:

```
for a in range(1,11):
    for b in range(1,11):
        print(f'{a*b:3d}' , end = '|')
    print()
```

**Output** of **This Is My Code**:

```
  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|
  2|  4|  6|  8| 10| 12| 14| 16| 18| 20|
  3|  6|  9| 12| 15| 18| 21| 24| 27| 30|
  4|  8| 12| 16| 20| 24| 28| 32| 36| 40|
  5| 10| 15| 20| 25| 30| 35| 40| 45| 50|
  6| 12| 18| 24| 30| 36| 42| 48| 54| 60|
  7| 14| 21| 28| 35| 42| 49| 56| 63| 70|
  8| 16| 24| 32| 40| 48| 56| 64| 72| 80|
  9| 18| 27| 36| 45| 54| 63| 72| 81| 90|
 10| 20| 30| 40| 50| 60| 70| 80| 90|100|
```

This Is My Target:

```
  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|
  2|  4|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
  3|   |  9|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
  4|   |   | 16|   |   |   |   |   |   |
  5|   |   |   | 25|   |   |   |   |   |
  6|   |   |   |   | 36|   |   |   |   |
  7|   |   |   |   |   | 49|   |   |   |
  8|   |   |   |   |   |   | 64|   |   |
  9|   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 81|   |
 10|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |100|
```

Comment: Please include your expected output as [formatted text](/help/formatting), not a [screenshot](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works :

```
for a in range(1,11):
    for b in range(1,11):
        if a == b or a == 1 or b == 1:
            print(f'{a*b:3d}' , end = '|')
        else:
            print(f'   ' , end = '|')
    print()
```

To remove the `|` and get quite the same thing as in the image you provided, switch `end = '|'` for `end = ''`

```
for a in range(1,11):
    for b in range(1,11):
        if a == b or a == 1 or b == 1:
            print(f'{a*b:3d}' , end = '')
        else:
            print(f'   ' , end = '')
    print()
```